# How to find out logical interface name of tap0?

Tags: linux, openwrt

Well, the question is given. I have tap0 interface connecting to a server which provides IPv6 addresses. I would like to set my RDNSS settings in radvd config and I need the logical interface name of tap0 to do that.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with `logical interface name` but the interface name for `tap0` is just `tap0`. You can check with `brctl` if `tap0` is attached to the  `lan` or `wan` bridge

Comment: There is a /etc/config/network file in my system, where every interface I intend to use has a logical interface name. This ifname is a free pick. In /etc/config/radvd config interface settings are referenced by this logical interface name.
The problem is that openvpn creates tap0 therefore I cant specify a logical interface name for that, could I?